# Requiring electron dialog from render process is undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using electron and am trying to open a file browser when a user clicks on button. From the render process I am trying to include the elctron.dialog package like this.

```
const dialog = require( 'electron' ).dialog;

console.log( dialog );
```

However the result from the console log is `undefined`

I am absolutely sure I am in the rendering process so I am not sure why this is not working. The documentation suggests that this is the correct way of doing things but it appears to not be working.

This is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "./main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^0.4.1"
  }
}
```

This is my `main.js` file

```
    'use strict';

    var app = require( 'app' );
    var BrowserWindow = require( 'browser-window' );
    var ipc = require( 'ipc' );

    var mainWindow = null;

    app.on(
        'ready', function () {
            mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
                {
                    frame : true,
                    height: 700,
                    width : 500
                }
            );

            mainWindow.loadUrl( 'file://' + __dirname + '/app/index.html' );

            mainWindow.openDevTools();
            mainWindow.on(
                'closed', function () {
                    mainWindow = null;
                }
            );

        }
    );

    ipc.on(
        'close-main-window', function () {
            app.quit();
        }
    );
```

this is the rendered process file

```
    // Add your index.js code in this file
    var ipc = require( 'ipc' );

    const dialog = require( 'electron' ).dialog;

    console.log( dialog );
```

This is the console

[image]

Is this incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried the Remote module? `const dialog = require('electron').remote.dialog`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few hours of looking into it [someone else](https://discuss.atom.io/t/requiring-electron-dialog-from-render-process-is-undefined/27877) pointed out to me that the "new" way (4/15/16) of doing this is the following.

```
var remote = require('remote');
var dialog = remote.require('dialog');

dialog.showOpenDialog({ 
  properties: [ 'openFile' ] }, function ( filename ) {
    console.log( filename.toString() );
  }
);
```

You must require `remote` and then from remote require dialog. It looks like you no longer need to require `electron`

Answer (score 35):

On the Renderer process, you must use the Remote module.

```
const dialog = require('electron').remote.dialog
```

More info:
[Electron Dialog API](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md)
[Electron Remote API](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md)

Comment: I posted my solution above. Your method appears to work in some other versions but not in mine.

Comment: This is now outdated, as `remote` is no longer part of electron. Use `@electron/remote`.

Comment: The links are dead.

Answer (score 12):

I'm surprised none of the answers mention this yet, but since the `remote` module has been removed and it's preferable not to use the userland `remote` for a variety of reasons discussed [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408), you'll want to use ipc to have the main process show the dialog.

renderer.js:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
ipcRenderer.invoke("showDialog", "message");
```

main.js:

```
const { ipcMain, dialog } = require("electron");
ipcMain.handle("showDialog", (e, message) => {
    dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow, { message });
});
```

Comment: it is insanely hard to find this solution considering it is so simple

Comment: Ditto @Nestoro. This got me out of a fix.

Comment: I had a similar approach in my project, but it didn’t work properly. You have two differences which helped: (a) `ipcRenderer.invoke() - I had `sendSync` which seems to hang; (b) `ipcMain.handle()` - I had `ipcMain.on()`: I don’t know that also makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: `handle` and `invoke` go together and are the newer APIs. They're similar to `send` and `on`. Maybe `send`/`on` would work fine for you @Manngo

Comment: @pushkin No, `send`/`on` seemed to be crashing. I was also having problems with writing to a file afterwards, but I could fix that using the `invoke` promise. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Electron in the newest version have changed the way of requiring the modules. The modules are encapsulated within the electron Name space.

```
// for getting the electrons modules here the new method now i'm using 1.7.12 Electron version (i don't know what that will be in the future)
// you require electron first! it's a name space (module)
var electron = require("electron");
var remote = electron.remote; // you get all the subModuls directly as property (cool incapsulation)
//remote = require("remote") ===> will not work!!!!

// for dialog it's the same !! but we now use remote as modul
var dialog = remote.dialog;
```

Also you can use this syntax, to import several modules with less writing and by gathering them all together:

```
var {remote, ipcRenderer, someOtherModulFromElectron} = electron;
```

for example in the main.js (main process) we could write such a call:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = electron;
```

in place of :

```
const electron = require('electron')

// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app

// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

//modul for bar menu
const Menu = electron.Menu
```

Answer (score 5):

Accroding to https://github.com/electron/remote
The remote module was deprecated in Electron 12, `@electron/remote` is the replacement.

```
$ npm install --save @electron/remote
```

In `main.js`:

```
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
```

I also have to set few `webPreferences` for BrowserWindow

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
```

In `renderer.js`:

```
const {dialog} = require('@electron/remote')

function showError() {
    dialog.showErrorBox(...)
}
```

After that `dialog` is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of electron made some change to dialog call for security, like you can call dialog in the main process (like index.js) but you can't call direct in the renderer process (like render.js), so have to use [ipc](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/structures/ipc-renderer-event)

In this example: the main process handles dialog through a preload and renders access dialog by calling the main process

[resources](https://medium.com/developer-rants/opening-system-dialogs-in-electron-from-the-renderer-6daf49782fd8)

> index.js

```
const createWindow = () => {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
});

...

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    ipcMain.handle("dialog", async (event, method, params) => {
        const result = await dialog[method](params);
        return result;
    });
});
```

> preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {
  openDialog: (method, config) => ipcRenderer.invoke("dialog", method, config),
});
```

> render.js

```
 const dialogConfig = {
  title: "Select a file",
  buttonLabel: "This one will do",
  properties: ["openFile"],
};
const { canceled, filePaths } = await electron.openDialog("showOpenDialog",dialogConfig);
console.log(canceled, filePaths);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works in the script of the html file  :

```
const remote = require('electron').remote 

const dialog = remote.dialog;

dialog.showErrorBox('Error title', 'error')
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was because I was using `node index.js`. What worked instead was using `npm start` while having this in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron index.js"
  },
```