# Uncaught ReferenceError: dialog is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to create a button in [electron](/questions/tagged/electron) that opens a `dialog` to open a file. (and in this example, simply print its name)

This is the button in my `index.html`:

```
 <div class="alse-element">
     <input id="select-song" type="button" value="select song" onclick="select_song()"/>
 </div>
```

From [dialog | Electron](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialog), it is said to import `dialog` in a renderer file like this:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote
console.log(dialog)
```

So this is my `renderer.js`:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote

function select_song() {
    dialog.showOpenDialog(
        {properties: ['openFile']}, 
        filename => {
            console.log(filename)
        }
    )
}
```

However, when I press the button, this message is printed in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dialog is not defined
    at select_song (renderer.js:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:14)
```

---

I tried [Philip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36638185/6282576):

```
const dialog = require('electron').remote.dialog
```

But it didn't work (same error)

---

I tried [Edgar Martinez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36653450/6282576):

```
var remote = require('remote');
var dialog = remote.require('dialog');
```

But I get this error (and if use `const` instead of `var`, I get the same error as above):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showOpenDialog' of undefined
    at select_song (renderer.js:5)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:14)
```

---

I tried [D.Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40655767/6282576):

```
const remote = require('electron').remote 
const dialog = remote.dialog;
```

But it didn't work either (same error)

---

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you try this way 
var electron = require("electron");
var remote = electron.remote;
var dialog = remote.dialog;

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showOpenDialog' of undefined`

Comment: after requiring can you put a console.log(dialog). is it undefined or it has some properties

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Thank you, after doing what you said, I found another error and fixed it.

Comment: Cool happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't notice the `require is not defined` at the top of console.

[image]

After searching for it, I found [Sathiraumesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55908510/6282576), and after adding `webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}` to the `main.js` file:

```
main_window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
})
```

The same code, suggested in Electron documenation, works:

```
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote

function select_song() {
    dialog.showOpenDialog(
        {properties: ['openFile']}, 
        filename => {
            console.log(filename)
        }
    )
}
```

[image]