# Import dialog in preload.js returns undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to understand how context isolation works in electron. I want to expose the `dialog.showErrorBox` function from the `electron` module to the renderer process. As i understand the following code in `preload.js` should be sufficient:

```
import {contextBridge, dialog} from 'electron'

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
  'electron',
  {
      showErrorDialog: dialog.showErrorBox
  }
```

Then in the renderer process I should be able to call this function as

```
window.electron.showErrorDialog(string, string)
```

However when importing electron in `preload.js` it appears as if it has no property `dialog` so that the import statement above returns `dialog = undefined`.

I have a feeling this has more to do with which properties the electron module exposes in the `preload.js` more than context isolation. It looks to me like there are several APIs which could be useful to expose to the renderer but are unavailable in `preload.js` (e.g. dialog, inAppPurchase) how is one supposed to use these?

This is basically a duplicate of
[Requiring electron dialog from render process is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637201/requiring-electron-dialog-from-render-process-is-undefined)
however the answers to that question are outdated as they use the `remote` API which is no longer part of electron.